# Question on reversing a string

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I get the following output: olleh�hello but can't figure out where I'm going wrong!

```
 int main()
    {

       char hello[6] = "hello";
       char temp[6]; 
       unsigned int t = 0;
       for(int i=strlen(hello)-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
       if(t<strlen(hello))
        {
          temp[t] = hello[i];
          t++;
        }
      }
      cout << temp;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You've made your temp array 6 elements long as needed.  But you never write the 6th element.  The zero.

Comment: By the way, you don't really need to check `if(t<strlen(hello))` as `t` and `i` are coupled.

Answer (score 7):

You need a null terminator at the end of the string:

```
int main()
{

   char hello[6] = "hello";
   char temp[6]; 
   unsigned int t = 0;
   for(int i=strlen(hello)-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
   if(t<strlen(hello))
    {
      temp[t] = hello[i];
      t++;
    }
  }
  temp[t] = '\0';
  cout << temp;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you tagged the question as [C++], so here's C++ way to reverse string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string hello = "hello";
    std::reverse(hello.begin(), hello.end());
    std::cout << hello << std::endl;
}
```

it's difficult to make any mistake here

Answer (score 3):

You aren't terminating `temp` with a null (`\0`), so `temp` isn't a valid string and `cout` doesn't know quite what to do with it.  Your problem will go away if you add:

```
temp[5] = 0;
```

after the `for` loop.

Comment: "`temp` is an invalid string literal" - `temp` is a variable, it cannot be a literal.